# Styling Material-UI Drawer component with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to port the styling of the Drawer component below, into Styled Components.

```
    <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper
      }}
    >
```

,where `paper` is styled as follows:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  drawerPaper: {
    position: "relative",
    width: 240px
  }
});
```

I have no idea of how can I customize `paper` prop through Styled Components. The following styled component syntax does not work:

```
export const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
    position: "relative";
    width: 240px;
`;
```

The [source-code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Drawer/Drawer.js) for this component indicates that this is passed as props as `PaperProps` but I can still not find a way to override it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have given my answer in a comment but since I don't have enough reputation I can not comment. Anyway,look at the styled component [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components). It says that :

> if you attempt to style a Drawer with variant permanent, you will
>   likely need to affect the Drawer's underlying paper style. However,
>   this is not the root element of Drawer and therefore styled-components
>   customization as above will not work. You can workaround this by using
>   stable JSS class names, but the most reliable approach is to use the
>   classes property to introduce an override style, and then style it
>   with higher specificity via &.

Please also look at the example given of button as well. If you still can't figure out comment here and I will try to help further.

Answer (score 7):

I have recently given an example in https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-k9l9h

I hope it helps:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import styled from "styled-components";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  drawer: {
    position: "absolute",
    overflowX: "hidden",
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 2,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      position: "relative",
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer
    },
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: 0,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9 + 1
    }
  }
});

const StyledDrawer = styled(Drawer)`
  ${({ theme, open }) => {
    const classes = styles(theme);
    return {
      ...classes.drawer,
      ...(open ? classes.drawerOpen : classes.drawerClose)
    };
  }}

  .MuiDrawer-paper {
    ${({ theme, open }) => {
      const classes = styles(theme);
      return open ? classes.drawerOpen : classes.drawerClose;
    }}

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 2px;
    }
    &:hover {
      &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      display: none;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`;

const PersistentDrawerLeft = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledDrawer variant="permanent" open={isOpen}>
        <span>sidebar</span>
        <button onClick={handleDrawerClose}>close</button>
      </StyledDrawer>
      <span>Content</span>
      <button onClick={handleDrawerOpen}>open</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersistentDrawerLeft;
```

Comment: Can't we just pass `<StyledDrawer variant="permanent" classes={{ paper: { width: '200'px } }}` with styled-components?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually fairly easy. You can pass your own Component that the paper object will use allowing you to easily impart your own styling.

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
const StyledPaper = styled.div`
   // my styles
`;

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Drawer
       // normal props
       PaperProps={{ component : StyledPaper }}
    >
      // drawer content
    </Drawer>
  )
}
```

Another option is to also have the first child of the drawer impart the styling. Since the paper has `display: flex` you can just put `flex: 1` on your child and it will grow to the full size of the paper.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Drawer
       // normal props
    >
      <StyledDiv>
        My Content
      </StyledDiv>
    </Drawer>
  )
}
```

Comment: This was a great solution, thank you for sharing!